# Integrating Java Language into Visual Studio 2017

Tags: java, plugins, visual-studio-2017, ide, visual-studio-extensions

I'm familiar with the C set of languages such as C/C++, C# and I've learned a little bit of Python. I'd now like to try my hand at Java.

I currently have Visual Studio 2017 CE installed with most of its packages and features. The storage capacity of my drives is mostly spent. Therefore I do not want to install another large scale IDE application such as Net Beans, IntelliJ, or Eclipse consuming more disk space and ram.

I'd want to be able to use Visual Studio 2017. The only thing I have found so far is this Visual Studio plugin `Java Language Support` found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.JavaLanguageSupport).

It appears that this plugin is compatible with Visual Studio 2015 and earlier. I have searched google thoroughly for either other plugins or extensions, or ways to make this one work and to no avail, my search results came up effortless. I've also searched through Microsofts - Visual Studios websites and again found nothing helpful...

Is there any workaround to getting this to integrate into Visual Studio 2017? Are there other plugins or extensions for 2017 that I wasn't able to find? What other options or alternatives do I have without having to install another IDE? I'd prefer to use the IDE I already have installed and configured to my preferences!

---

**Note** - I'm not sure if this is the correct location for this type of question if not please point me in the right direction so I can migrate this question there!

Answer (score 0):

As you have said , for VS 2017, there is no such extension.

And I suggest you stick with the best tool for a language while developing in it.
 VS is for microsoft based languages and you should use it for that only.

Or you can try **Visual Studio Code**. I am not using it to develop in Java.

Here is the link.
[Java in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java)

I hope it would help.

Comment: The thing is here I have downloaded IntelliJ CE as a test or trial and I see that it's rich with features, but that would take me a month just to learn how to configure the settings and properties correctly before I can even begin to import any kind of packages... When I was learning Python, I had the interpreter installed, and yes Visual Studio has support for it, however, I found that with Python, I like it better by integrating it into the command prompt. I just use notepad++ to write my Python Scripts and I use cmd to run and test them... NO IDE! As for Java that's a different beast! ...

Comment: With C/C++ and C# I'll stick with Visual Studio for now! I've tried GCC and Clang for C/C++ and don't get me wrong they are good, but I'm just so accustomed to "shitty" MS compiler and linker errors lol! If I ever do finally leave Microsoft... and decide to pick up Linux then I might go with GCC and or Clang...